# Prestashop Text not display almost everywhere

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I am newbie in Prestashop. I use Prestashop 1.6x. Whenever I put my Prestashop site on server most of the text are not display such as CART, Quick view ,Buy now etc.

Here is the Image which describe the actual situation.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

(Yes, My Prestashop site working fine on localhost).

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Answer (score 2):

Those are texts popping out on hover only, correct? It would be great to be able to examine the real site. But the issue might be there, in how text is managed once you hover on an element. As the product name is there before hovering as well

Comment: No there is no text before or after hover. One image shows my localhost which have all the texts and other one depicts the site over server without any text

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say that the text you are not seeing is supposed to be shown when you hover on the product, so it might have something to do with that